# Need help with differential/integral calculus question about position, velocity, and acceleration.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

A train is traveling at 44 feet/second. When the brakes are applied, the train decelerates at a constant rate of 0.4 feet per second^2. How far does it travel before it stops?

I keep circling back to finding a position function by integrating the velocity or acceleration given but I don't know how I would do that. Please help!

Comment: There's a direct formula for this problem. But, it seems your teacher wants you to find it. Show your efforts so far and some body may help you.

Comment: Suppose the train applies the brakes at $t=0$. What does the graph of the velocity look like for $t\geq0$? When does the train come to a halt? How can you use this graph to find the distance the train travelled before it comes to a halt?

Comment: You don't know how to integrate acceleration (or deceleration) to get velocity?

Comment: Awesome points! The graph of the velocity would be a straight line with a negative slope since decceleration is constant. Thank you all also for helping while also encouraging me to come to the conclusions myself! @Ripi2